# Why Any's methods are not abstract or native?

Tags: java, class, methods, kotlin

**Java**

[Source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java)

Object's methods are marked as native, so it's easy to understand they are implemented behind the scene

**Kotlin**

[Source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.70/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Any.kt#L22)

```
   public open class Any {
        public open operator fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean
        public open fun hashCode(): Int
        public open fun toString(): String
    }
```

Any's methods are not marked as native or abstract, so question is next:

When and how Any's methods are generated and why I can't just copy-paste Any class and compile without errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Any`'s methods are not generated. The compiler maps `Any` to `java.lang.Object`, which provides the implementations of methods as part of the JDK.

The methods are not marked as abstract, because `Any` is not an abstract class. The methods are not marked as `native` because the mapping of Kotlin standard library classes to JDK classes is not unique to the `Any` class, and other methods mapped in a similar way are not native.

Comment: Thank you for reply. And how can I find which methods are mapped?